# Seeding E&R with some high level electronics questions

Tags: discussion, meta

While I don't have anything against the hobbyist culture, I feel that if E&R has to become a center of knowledge we will have to start ask and answer hard questions. High level theoretical topics like microelectronics, semiconductors, VLSI, embedded systems, computer organizations, robot locomotion, control systems,materials etc must be included in our discussions if we want to do something as high quality as stackoverflow.

Should we start making a list which will be used to seed the E&R site?

I am in a hurry right now but will submit mine in a short time.  Meanwhile, it would be nice if the rest of the community started on a list as well.

Comment: Note: There was a recent question and blog post about a related issue on SO here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56817 and here: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/

Answer (score 3):

While I agree that we want higher-level questions, I think that it would be difficult to come up with high-quality 'fake' questions.

Instead, maybe we should try to pay attention for good, high-level questions in our jobs and at school, and bring them here rather than (or in addition to) a senior engineer or professor - Intentionally make the assumption that this is a site for hard questions, even if it's not quite ready yet.

Comment: I agree, bringing good questions here is effective. I have a few questions that I can bring here as they come up. Mostly I hate z-transforms.

Comment: I never mentioned fake questions. But I have found that generally many of us avoid posting high level questions.

Comment: @Rick - Exactly.  My proposal is that we stop doing that, and actively work to fix the situation by posting good, high-level questions to which we have already found an answer independently.

Comment: @reemrevnivek, thanks for the support. I am a a student so it will be actually easy for me to come up with some of the "hard problems" I face in my classes

Comment: in class and in the world have not been similar to me, excluding rare cases.

Comment: Siding with Kortuk here.  A hard homework question does not a good question make.

Comment: I was not going to ask my homework here guys. I do work on some private projects (highly theoretical kind, maybe going to publish a paper soon). I pointed out that I am a student because that would mean I would be more close to theory (at least closer than professional who are not exactly in R&D).

Answer (score 1):

I really think seeding with questions that you find intentionally is not how this should be approached.

People come here when they have questions, and ask them, and we answer them. We will start to get higher level questions as time progresses.I think as the question becomes more basic the more often we will see them, but at some point most basics exist.

I think fake seeding with many questions is not a great way to go about it as it weights it to what you consider "valuable" and the person posting all the questions pick what is right.

Comment: Two things - First, we've got over 1,000 questions: When will most of the basics exist?  Second, weighting it with what we consider valuable (hard questions) is precisely what we want to do.  I'd doubt the quality of questions generated this way, but that's not the issue you brought up.

Comment: you are misunderstanding, due to me not communicating well. Like you state in your answer, fake questions are not the way to go. Real questions from people trying to figured something out is the best method. If someone reads a question and is missing background knowledge, also asking a question about the more basic concept is effective in my mind. the direction we are going we are building up to more complicated questions with basics explained.  1000 questions is almost nothing in the realm of electronics.

Comment: 1000 is a substantial number by any respect (for anything human generated). And we don't have even 5 of the questions which we would consider a "hard problem"

Comment: replace we with I. I understand your statement, but as you come across hard problems you should ask them. I think fake seeding is a problem, also, there are many questions on here that most users consider a hard problem. It is only a few of us with professional or academic experience that find it easy.

Comment: With all due respect, if we want to produce something which is equivalent to StackOverflow its essential to have questions which the professionals will consider hard. We have plethora of questions about interfacing and uC if we want only that then we may as well name it Micro controller community.

Comment: i constantly see very basic questions on stack overflow. there are hard questions also. as more professionals join the site we will have an increase in real questions. it just needs time.

Comment: and why would these professionals join? they do not have any incentive to join a website full of hobbyist questions. Even StackOverflow had to seed there questions.

Comment: I would consider about 6 of the people on the site professionals, why did they come here? They chose to take part. As the site picks up there will be more. Build it and they will come?